# Apache Jackrabbit Oak 1.8 Indexing - Lucene does not index binary properties in aggregated node

Tags: indexing, lucene, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

I have following index:

```
oak:index
      jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
      dms-lucene-fulltext-index
         compatVersion = 2
         async = async
         jcr:primaryType = oak:QueryIndexDefinition
         evaluatePathRestrictions = true
         type = lucene
         tags = fulltext
         aggregates
            jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
            nt:file
               jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
               include0
                  path = jcr:content
                  jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured
```

And i have following file node in a folder:

```
folder
   jcr:created = 2018-02-24T14:32:09.550+01:00
   jcr:createdBy = 
   jcr:primaryType = nt:folder
   jcr:uuid = 5c3e4689-84e9-4e34-8b14-029f62172812
   test.txt
      jcr:created = 2018-02-24T14:32:09.674+01:00
      jcr:createdBy = 14
      jcr:primaryType = nt:file
      jcr:content
         jcr:encoding = utf-8
         jcr:lastModifiedBy = 14
         jcr:mimeType = text/plain; charset=utf-8
         jcr:data = the quick brown fox
         jcr:lastModified = 2018-02-24T14:32:09.673+01:00
         jcr:primaryType = nt:resource
         jcr:uuid = 52f224e8-db57-4879-9d6a-94862f65fb8d
```

If I execute following query, i get that file as result:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:file] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('/folder') AND CONTAINS(*,'plain')
```

So the mimeType is in the index. But the binary not, cause following query has no result:

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:file] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE('/folder') AND CONTAINS(*,'fox')
```

I hope that anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation, i finally found a solution for the problem.

I added following dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then my custom tika configuration is also loaded and binary properties are indexed!

Comment: Do you mean that you could get your binary indexed without specifying index-rule??

Answer (score 0):

You'd also need to have an `nt:file` index rule in your definition.

So, just have following in your def (along with your aggregate rule)

```
+ /oak:index/dms-lucene-fulltext-index
    + indexRules
         + nt:file
```

You don't need any property definition - the index rule is the starting point for indexing process - aggregate rules would be consulted after node being index matches index rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Another strange thing is that I have a custum tika configuration in a tika node within the index configuration, but oak says on console:

"Loaded default Tika Config from classpath jar..."

Meanwhile, I think it's a bug or something... :/

Comment: I think I should have written the answer better (clarified now) - the index rule I mentioned was an additional change you would require for aggregates to come into play.

Comment: It even works without the index rule (like mentioned above).